# How to create H3 shapefiles in a particular area to use in Tableau

Tags: python, gis, tableau-api, shapefile, h3

I'd like to visualize some point data in Tableau and create a density map using H3 hexagons at resolutions 4 through 10. I haven't been able to find a way to create the shapefiles I need using Python, but that's the only language I'm somewhat comfortable with.

I would only really need to look at a few (U.S.) states, and so could limit the shapefiles to a reasonable bounding box.

Ideally, I'd like to create a map with several layers/pages that a user could toggle through on Tableau, with each being a different resolution.

Edit:
I created a bounding box for my area and I'm trying to use H3 (python) Polyfill. I can't quite get it to work, and I still need a way to download these shapefiles so I can put them in Tableau.

```
w = shp.Writer('geojson')
# assign POLYGON (5) as shapeType
w.shapeType = 5
# add a "name" field of type "Character"
w.field('name', 'C')
w.poly([[[-75.723133,41.250432],  # upper left(nw)
        [-72.608509,41.250432]],   # upper right(ne)
        [[-72.608509,39.746775],   # lower right(se)
        [-75.723133,39.746775],   # lower left(sw)
        [-75.723133,41.250432]]]) # first point again

bbox=w.record('bbox')
```

```
h3_res4= h3.polyfill(bbox, 4)
```

And I'm getting this error... Any ideas? I think I'm missing something.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-d300c198762b> in <module>
      1 # Use h3 polyfill at each resolution
      2 
----> 3 h3_res4= h3.polyfill(bbox, 4)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h3/api/_api_template.py in polyfill(geojson, res, geo_json_conformant)
    522         unordered collection of H3Cell
    523         """
--> 524         mv = _cy.polyfill(geojson, res, geo_json_conformant=geo_json_conformant)
    525 
    526         return _out_unordered(mv)

geo.pyx in h3._cy.geo.polyfill()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

EDIT: 4-23-2021

```
#a geojson-style dict of the U.S. states (not my bbox, but got this from my wonderful professor)
us_geojson_dict= {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-94.81758,49.38905],[-94.64,48.84],[-94.32914,48.67074],[-93.63087,48.60926],[-92.61,48.45],[-91.64,48.14],[-90.83,48.27],[-89.6,48.01],[-89.272917,48.019808],[-88.378114,48.302918],[-87.439793,47.94],[-86.461991,47.553338],[-85.652363,47.220219],[-84.87608,46.900083],[-84.779238,46.637102],[-84.543749,46.538684],[-84.6049,46.4396],[-84.3367,46.40877],[-84.14212,46.512226],[-84.091851,46.275419],[-83.890765,46.116927],[-83.616131,46.116927],[-83.469551,45.994686],[-83.592851,45.816894],[-82.550925,45.347517],[-82.337763,44.44],[-82.137642,43.571088],[-82.43,42.98],[-82.9,42.43],[-83.12,42.08],[-83.142,41.975681],[-83.02981,41.832796],[-82.690089,41.675105],[-82.439278,41.675105],[-81.277747,42.209026],[-80.247448,42.3662],[-78.939362,42.863611],[-78.92,42.965],[-79.01,43.27],[-79.171674,43.466339],[-78.72028,43.625089],[-77.737885,43.629056],[-76.820034,43.628784],[-76.5,44.018459],[-76.375,44.09631],[-75.31821,44.81645],[-74.867,45.00048],[-73.34783,45.00738],[-71.50506,45.0082],[-71.405,45.255],[-71.08482,45.30524],[-70.66,45.46],[-70.305,45.915],[-69.99997,46.69307],[-69.237216,47.447781],[-68.905,47.185],[-68.23444,47.35486],[-67.79046,47.06636],[-67.79134,45.70281],[-67.13741,45.13753],[-66.96466,44.8097],[-68.03252,44.3252],[-69.06,43.98],[-70.11617,43.68405],[-70.645476,43.090238],[-70.81489,42.8653],[-70.825,42.335],[-70.495,41.805],[-70.08,41.78],[-70.185,42.145],[-69.88497,41.92283],[-69.96503,41.63717],[-70.64,41.475],[-71.12039,41.49445],[-71.86,41.32],[-72.295,41.27],[-72.87643,41.22065],[-73.71,40.931102],[-72.24126,41.11948],[-71.945,40.93],[-73.345,40.63],[-73.982,40.628],[-73.952325,40.75075],[-74.25671,40.47351],[-73.96244,40.42763],[-74.17838,39.70926],[-74.90604,38.93954],[-74.98041,39.1964],[-75.20002,39.24845],[-75.52805,39.4985],[-75.32,38.96],[-75.071835,38.782032],[-75.05673,38.40412],[-75.37747,38.01551],[-75.94023,37.21689],[-76.03127,37.2566],[-75.72205,37.93705],[-76.23287,38.319215],[-76.35,39.15],[-76.542725,38.717615],[-76.32933,38.08326],[-76.989998,38.239992],[-76.30162,37.917945],[-76.25874,36.9664],[-75.9718,36.89726],[-75.86804,36.55125],[-75.72749,35.55074],[-76.36318,34.80854],[-77.397635,34.51201],[-78.05496,33.92547],[-78.55435,33.86133],[-79.06067,33.49395],[-79.20357,33.15839],[-80.301325,32.509355],[-80.86498,32.0333],[-81.33629,31.44049],[-81.49042,30.72999],[-81.31371,30.03552],[-80.98,29.18],[-80.535585,28.47213],[-80.53,28.04],[-80.056539,26.88],[-80.088015,26.205765],[-80.13156,25.816775],[-80.38103,25.20616],[-80.68,25.08],[-81.17213,25.20126],[-81.33,25.64],[-81.71,25.87],[-82.24,26.73],[-82.70515,27.49504],[-82.85526,27.88624],[-82.65,28.55],[-82.93,29.1],[-83.70959,29.93656],[-84.1,30.09],[-85.10882,29.63615],[-85.28784,29.68612],[-85.7731,30.15261],[-86.4,30.4],[-87.53036,30.27433],[-88.41782,30.3849],[-89.18049,30.31598],[-89.593831,30.159994],[-89.413735,29.89419],[-89.43,29.48864],[-89.21767,29.29108],[-89.40823,29.15961],[-89.77928,29.30714],[-90.15463,29.11743],[-90.880225,29.148535],[-91.626785,29.677],[-92.49906,29.5523],[-93.22637,29.78375],[-93.84842,29.71363],[-94.69,29.48],[-95.60026,28.73863],[-96.59404,28.30748],[-97.14,27.83],[-97.37,27.38],[-97.38,26.69],[-97.33,26.21],[-97.14,25.87],[-97.53,25.84],[-98.24,26.06],[-99.02,26.37],[-99.3,26.84],[-99.52,27.54],[-100.11,28.11],[-100.45584,28.69612],[-100.9576,29.38071],[-101.6624,29.7793],[-102.48,29.76],[-103.11,28.97],[-103.94,29.27],[-104.45697,29.57196],[-104.70575,30.12173],[-105.03737,30.64402],[-105.63159,31.08383],[-106.1429,31.39995],[-106.50759,31.75452],[-108.24,31.754854],[-108.24194,31.34222],[-109.035,31.34194],[-111.02361,31.33472],[-113.30498,32.03914],[-114.815,32.52528],[-114.72139,32.72083],[-115.99135,32.61239],[-117.12776,32.53534],[-117.295938,33.046225],[-117.944,33.621236],[-118.410602,33.740909],[-118.519895,34.027782],[-119.081,34.078],[-119.438841,34.348477],[-120.36778,34.44711],[-120.62286,34.60855],[-120.74433,35.15686],[-121.71457,36.16153],[-122.54747,37.55176],[-122.51201,37.78339],[-122.95319,38.11371],[-123.7272,38.95166],[-123.86517,39.76699],[-124.39807,40.3132],[-124.17886,41.14202],[-124.2137,41.99964],[-124.53284,42.76599],[-124.14214,43.70838],[-124.020535,44.615895],[-123.89893,45.52341],[-124.079635,46.86475],[-124.39567,47.72017],[-124.68721,48.184433],[-124.566101,48.379715],[-123.12,48.04],[-122.58736,47.096],[-122.34,47.36],[-122.5,48.18],[-122.84,49],[-120,49],[-117.03121,49],[-116.04818,49],[-113,49],[-110.05,49],[-107.05,49],[-104.04826,48.99986],[-100.65,49],[-97.22872,49.0007],[-95.15907,49],[-95.15609,49.38425],[-94.81758,49.38905]]]}
```

```
# Use h3 polyfill at each resolution
#res 4
h3_res4= h3.polyfill(us_geojson_dict, 4, geo_json_conformant= True)
```

Comment: Try using QGIS. There is a learning curve of course, but it free, packed with GIS functionality and runs on multiple systems. QGIS can generate a hex grid layer pretty easily, look under the Vector -> Research Tools menu

Comment: Tableau can create dynamic hexagons for maps without the need for a shapefile. It isn't trivial, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43641900/1047635) describes how to do it.

Comment: @matt_black I don't think this answers the OP's question if they actually need H3. H3 grids are not arbitrary hexbins, they have stable identifiers for use across different systems, so if you want to align your data with someone else's H3 data using an arbitrary hexbin doesn't suffice.

Comment: Hi @devo0241,

`h3-py` maintainer here. Could you provide a simple `bbox` example that gives you the error above? If you could print out the full data structure in Python, that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I actually was able to generate the hexagons I need (as @nrabinowitz commented, they did need to be H3) however, I'm unsure how to get them out of my notebook... I'll edit my post to show. Thank you all for the input!

Comment: @AJFriend I just edited my post. I'm not very comfortable with creating shapes from scratch, but I uploaded what I did using pyshp, I never got my bbox to work correctly, but a professor gave me a US json to use that ran, but I'm not sure what I have now in my notebook, or how to get it out in a format I can use in Tableau.